# Powershell Get-ChildItem Include\Exclude - simple script not working properly

Tags: powershell, script, ps1

Im trying to run the following code as a powershell script,but I cant get it to work. 1st,the following works with one `-Include` item but I cant seem to get it to work with multiple ones. 2nd, the `-Exclude` perimeter doesn't seem to work. I still get files from the *C:\Windows* and *C:\Program Files* directorys .

```
$Include = "*.zip","*.rar","*.tar","*.7zip"
$exclude = "C:\Windows","C:\Program Files"
Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Include $Include -Exclude $Exclude -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Note: The purpose of this script is to find all compressed files on the system. I know this is probably really simple but I just cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-Exclude` parameter has never really worked properly. It seems to match on the `Name` property, which is typically not very useful. You probably just have to do the filtering yourself:

```
$Include = "*.zip","*.rar","*.tar","*.7zip"
Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Include $Include -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | 
    ? { $_.FullName -notmatch "^C:\\Windows" -and $_.FullName -notmatch "^C:\\Program" } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

(By the way, `-Filter` is much, much faster than `-Include`. The downside is that you can't give it an array of patterns like you can with `-Include`. But it still may be faster even if you had to search four times. I couldn't say for sure. It might be worth testing if speed is important to you.)

Answer (score 6):

I agree with dangph that the -exclude doesn't work as expected.
When using -notmatch you can build a regex pattern with an or `|`.
This works here with the revised $include:

```
$Include = @('*.zip','*.rar','*.tar','*.7zip')
$exclude = [RegEx]'^C:\\Windows|^C:\\Program Files'
Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Include $Include -Recurse -Force -EA 0| 
  Where FullName -notmatch $exclude|
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

**EDit** Since the excluded folders are first level it is much faster to not iterate them at all, so a two step approach is more efficent:

```
$Include = @('*.zip','*.rar','*.tar','*.7zip')
$exclude = [RegEx]'^C:\\Windows|^C:\\Program Files'

Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Directory |
  Where FullName -notmatch $exclude|ForEach {
  Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Include $Include -Recurse -Force -EA 0| 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
}
```

Comment: Once I took out the `-Force` and the `-EA 0` it worked. I don't know why? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for that, PowerShell version differences. Both are supported in higher releases. `-EA 0` is just an abreviation for `-ErrorAction silentlycontinue`