# How to add a folder to Windows Search Excluded Folders with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-search

In Windows 10 version 1909 you can exclude folders from Windows search by going in:

*Settings > Searching Windows > Excluded Folders*

and add the excluded folders one by one.

[image]

As a result of that, all the files and folders contained in those folders (recursively) will be excluded from the search done in the **Windows Start Menu**.

What is the PowerShell command to add one folder to the *Windows Search Excluded Folders*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude the system directory using Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1196482/how-to-exclude-the-system-directory-using-powershell)

Comment: I don't think so: as far as I understood, that is for excluding folders from a search done within PowerShell. I edited the question to clarify the difference.

Comment: If you can exclude you can include using the include command

Comment: My question is about excluding folders from the Windows Start Menu search, the question you mentioned is for excluding folders from a search done within PowerShell.

Comment: I found this PowerShell cmdlet which seems applicable https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowssearch/set-windowssearchsetting?view=win10-ps; however, I do not see that it supports any exclude parameters to create those exclusions. I also see `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search` and it's keys/sub-keys may be applicable, but can't easily determine which values represent exclusions but maybe in `CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\WorkingSetRules\##` from what I can tell. You might have to hook in some `.net` or `c` code to run with PS is it's possble... ideas for others!!

Comment: Marco - In addition to the above, I also found https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-isearchfolderitemfactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN so with some poking around those documents and finding perhaps the C++ or C# code, you could put that into the PowerShell mix. I've done this many times in the past when PS cmdlets lack the functionality. You just set the code as your definition variable in PS and then use `add-type` to use that code accordingly in a nut shell. Maybe you or someone else can figure out a solution with some of those pointers.

Comment: Lastly, as I think this is what may do the exclusions specifically but not enough time to dig in and play with it right now: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-extidx-csm  I look forward to seeing the final solution that works....Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 Search parameters may be found in the registry under the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\WorkingSetRules`.

They are stocked in sub-keys named `0`, `1`, `2` etc.

As the items under each key are not documented, I would use templates.

Here is one a screenshot of one exclusion for the folder of `C:\Temp\PrintScreen`:

[image]

This uses a weird URL of :
`file:///C:\[bac78df2-ab37-4a4c-ba64-d7d57071563b]\Temp\PrintScreen\`.

However, most sources I have found claim that it also accepts URLs that are
written more simply. In that case, this would look like
`file:///C:\Temp\PrintScreen\`.

As Windows Search is disabled on my computer, you will need to test.
If it works, then a PowerShell script would be easy to write,
with the only problem being finding the next available number for a sub-key.

It would perhaps be useful to stop the Windows Search system service while this
registry update is done.

Comment: harry - I think PowerShell can handle all that actually... It can stop the service, count the keys, generate a new key based on next incremented value by one, and create everything you suggest with applicable values for the exclusions with that format you suggest that's more generic which might work, and then start the service back up. That's all really just trivial. I'd probably be curious why the other format has the "weird" GUID URL or whatever it is too and once confirmed why, then what not using it as such could mean; if it means much at all. I assume it means something but not important?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: PowerShell can certainly do all that. I have not found any explanation for the string `bac78df2-ab37-4a4c-ba64-d7d57071563b` in the URL, which is why counseled trying a normal one.